# capistrano3 tasks not retaining gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jenkins, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to update Capistrano to v3 using rvm1-capistrano and running into errors with the gemset.

The relevant section of the Capfile:

```
require 'rvm1/capistrano3'
#require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

My deploy.rb looks like:

```
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.1.5'
set :rvm_ruby_gemset, 'ruby-2.1.5@json-webservice'
set :branch, ENV["BRANCH_NAME"] || ENV["TAG_NAME"] || "master"
set :pty, true
```

Any other settings are host, repo_url, and the like.  The rake assets:precompile task fails with the following error because the job can't find the proper gemset:

```
DEBUG[bc474425] Command: cd /home/user/www/server-test/releases/20150103023617 && ( RAILS_ENV=stevedev /home/usr/www/mdm-server-test/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG[bc474425]     git@github.com:customgem/customgem.git (at 745-capistrano-3-upgrade) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
```

The Gemfile specifies the gem (a custom-built engine) in the main section:

```
gem "customgem", :git => 'git@github.com:customgem/customget.git', :branch => '745-capistrano-3-upgrade'
```

I've run a `bundle install` on the remote server manually so I know the gemset is actually on the remote server.

I've run `cap customenv rvm1:check` and recevied the following output:

```
DEBUG[bad87e27] Finished in 1.862 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
```

So it appears the capistrano job does have the proper settings.

Is there a variable I've left unset?

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3/issues/6#issuecomment-29296421

The code in this thread worked for me, by adding this custom cap task:

```
set :bundle_without, %w{development test}.join(' ')
set :bundle_roles, :all
namespace :bundler do
  desc "Install gems with bundler."
  task :install do
    on roles fetch(:bundle_roles) do
      within release_path do
        execute :bundle, "install", "--without #{fetch(:bundle_without)}"
      end
    end
  end
end
before 'deploy:updated', 'bundler:install'
```